# Using Lollipop's Transition API on a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-transitions

I've been reading multiple sources on how to implement Lollipop's Transition animation to seamlessly move between Activities and Fragments.

That said, I can't seem to make it work with `DialogFragment`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I've `Activity1` which hosts a list of items in a `ListView`. In its `onCreate()` method, I've made a request to enable transitions:

  ```
  @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this)
          .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_bounds_shared_element));

  ...
  ```
- I've built (and assigned) a custom adapter in a way I could listen to click events
  and be notified about what item are being clicked as well as its
  `View`. I used that information to compose my transition (setting
  `TransitionName` and whatnot) such as this:

  ```
  ...

  @Override public void onCardClicked(final View view, final Card card) {

      view.setTransitionName("rootLayout");

      final CardDetailsFragment fragment = CardDetailsFragment.newInstance(card);
      fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(CardFlowActivity.this)
          .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_bounds_shared_element));

  ...
  ```
- Lastly, I made a call to show my `CardDetailsFragment` which, as many of you should've guessed, is derived from `DialogFragment`.

  ```
  fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "detailed_card_view_" + card.getId());
  ```

But alas, it didn't worked the way I was expecting it to be. There's not even any animation save for the default fade-in one.

Am I missing something? Or is it the nature of `DialogFragment` that can't be used alongside with the new Transition API?

Comment: p.s., for those thinking about me missing `Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS`: I've already add it in my `themes.xml`. And I'm testing on a Lollipop device.

Comment: have you found an answer to this ? if so, can you please update the question.... I'm looking for the same